# Route traffic thru NTLM proxy when using Appium driver

Tags: c#, selenium, proxy, appium, browserstack

In my application, I am scheduling Mobile Application tests for clients app. using Browserstack.
Unfortunately, when client is running the test on his local computer, he is unable to establish connection with Browserstack. It occurred that all "non-internal" traffic is going thru NTLM proxy so my app can`t create direct connection to BS.

I was trying to change config files settings to use default proxy, but it didnt helped - I get 407 authorization error.
Currently I`m trying to make it working in the code directly, but with no luck. Moreover i read that AppiumDriver is not using any proxy related settings.

```
var proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.Kind = ProxyKind.AutoDetect;
proxy.IsAutoDetect = true;

AppiumOptions caps = new AppiumOptions();
caps.AddAdditionalCapability("browserstack.user", "user");
caps.AddAdditionalCapability("browserstack.key", "key");
caps.AddAdditionalCapability("device", "Samsung Galaxy S8");
caps.AddAdditionalCapability("os_version", "7.0");
caps.AddAdditionalCapability("name", string.Format("Requested 
time: {0}", DateTime.Now));
caps.AddAdditionalCapability("realMobile", true);
caps.AddAdditionalCapability("browserstack.idleTimeout", 300);
caps.AddAdditionalCapability("app", "MobileAppName");
caps.AddAdditionalCapability("ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS", true);
caps.Proxy = proxy;

try
{
 return new  
 AndroidDriver<OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Android.AndroidElement>(
 new Uri("https://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub"), caps);
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
 throw new Exception($"Couldn't create browserstack 
 instance. {e.Message + e.StackTrace}");
 }
 }
```

What I want to achieve is to force Appium Driver to use proxy and credentials defined on client`s computer to make connection with Browserstack hub.

Any suggestions are welcome as I`m struggling with the issue far too long now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Appium itself does not support passing proxy details programmatically. Relevant links for the same - [#1](https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/854), [#2](https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/955), [#3](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4968)

You may try to whitelist the BrowserStack Hub address in your client machine to connect to BrowserStack hub.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment! Adding browserstack addresses to the "whitelist" (so connection to BS won`t go thru proxy) was proposed, but at least for now, client do not want to make such changes in their proxy config. That is why i am trying to workaround this issue. As I am out of ideas, this topic is my last try to find any solution.